# Shared pointer from const pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose that I have a function that returns

```
const MyType*
```

Can I capture the result into a shared_ptr? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) to do it. By the way **there's a catch**: beware of the `const T` - `T` pointer sharing!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class MyType {
    public:
};

const MyType* fun() {
    return new MyType();
}

int main() {

    {
        shared_ptr<const MyType> new_ptr(fun());

        // Use your pointer..

        shared_ptr<MyType> other_ptr(new MyType());
        shared_ptr<const MyType> other_ptr2 = other_ptr; // T to const T, allowed

        shared_ptr<MyType> new_ptr2 = new_ptr; // const T to T - NOT ALLOWED
    }

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/OOPdLu

Answer (score 0):

A `shared_ptr<MyType const>` would do the trick, but before going that route, I'd be very, very sure that I can; if the returned value wasn't allocated with `new`, or is already in a `shared_ptr`, for example.

Comment: Just a note, you'd not declare the `shared_ptr` with the `*` in the template-argument :)

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` can accept a const type as it's type.

```
std::shared_ptr<const MyType>
```

So you could use it like:

```
std::shared_ptr<const MyType> pResult(SomeFunction());
```

This assumes however that the value returned from the function was `new`'d inside the function, and that the function caller assumes responsibility for the returned pointer.